# Confirm password error message in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, passwords

I'm trying to create an easy password confirmation, which looks like this

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="password">Password:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password" data-ng-model="myApp.password" required >
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="confirmPassword">Confirm password:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="confirmPassword" placeholder="Confirm password" data-ng-model="confirmPassword" required pw-check="password">
            <p class="msg-error" ng-show="create_player_form.confirmPassword.$error.pwmatch">
                Passwords don't match.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This HTML file is linked to controller defined like this:

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .controller('MyController', function ($scope, $state, $stateParams) {
(All the staff...)
}
```

and I use directive like this:

```
.directive('pwCheck', [function () {
            return {
                scope: {pwmatch: '='},
                require: 'ngModel',
                link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
                    var firstPassword = '#' + attrs.pwCheck;
                    elem.add(firstPassword).on('keyup', function () {
                        scope.$apply(function () {
                            var v = elem.val() === $(firstPassword).val();
                            ctrl.$setValidity("pwmatch", v);
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
        }]);
```

Everything is working, excluding the small error message under the confirmation input. Can anyone help me with making it appear?

I openly say, that I'm using: http://blog.brunoscopelliti.com/angularjs-directive-to-check-that-passwords-match/
and I see, that there is controller defined in different way, but I'd like to simply make it without changing present structure.

Comment: What problem are you facing with the error message , is it not appearing?

Comment: @Treck If you closely observe the example that you followed, it checks for the form name and then input tag with the name confirmPassword. If you observe your html code, it seems you are missing to give the name for the input tag                                                                                                       ng-show="create_player_form.confirmPassword.$error.pwmatch"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="password">Password:    </label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password" data-ng-model="myApp.password" required >
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="confirmPassword">Confirm password:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="password" name="confirmPassword" class="form-control" id="confirmPassword" placeholder="Confirm password" data-ng-model="confirmPassword" required pw-check="password">
        <p class="msg-error" ng-show="create_player_form.confirmPassword.$error.pwmatch">
            Passwords don't match.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Add name tag in the input name="confirmPassword" and then try .Also your form name will be "create_player_form"

Comment: Such a stupid, little bug... Thank you very much, now it's perfect.